# Match a panda's column with a list of files - lists are different lengths

Tags: python-3.x, api, jupyter-notebook, arcgis

Having an issue looping through two lists of different lengths and comparing.  What I need to do is check if a file already exists as an attachment.  So I am trying to find all the values in the pandas name column that match a value in the file list skip those and proceed attaching the rest.

```
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(attachmentFolder): 
            for filename in files:
                #create dataframe of existing attachments
                df2 = pd.DataFrame(featureAttachments)
                df2.reset_index() 
                #iterate through attachments to find names
                for row in df2.itertuples():
                    attName = (row.name)
                    parentid = (row.parentGlobalId)
                    #if existing attachment matches a filename
                    if filename == attName:
                        print('Attachment:{} already exists.'.format(attName))

                    else:
```